# Is it true that if the growth ratio of denominator is larger than the numerator then it is $\Theta(1)$?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, upper-lower-bounds

I need to prove this

$$\frac{(n+2)}{2^n}=\Theta(1)$$

and I found an explanation saying that because the growth ratio of the denominator is larger than the growth ratio of numerator but I don't believe that's the case for every division $\frac{1}{n}$ isn't $\Theta(1)$ for example. If it is possible I must find this without the use of the limit definition.

Comment: That is not true.

Comment: If you think $\tfrac1n\notin\Theta(1)$, could you spell out how you define $\Theta(f(n))$?

Comment: it is saying we need to prove that this is Θ(1) but i don't believe it is personally cause it hasn't a lower bound maybe there is a theorem or something that prove this?

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Big Oh notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) states "$f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ if $f$ is bounded both above and below by $g$ asymptotically". Do you think that $(n+2)/2^n$ has a lower bound?